# How do I select only the outline of an object that is transparent? [Photoshop]

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I hope you are well?

For a long time I always wanted to know how to do it easier.
Unfortunately, I have not figured it out.
I hope there is a professional here who can give me a hint.
I have an object, let's say a teddy bear, it is transparent and only the lines of the teddy bear are drawn in black.
Now I want to select only the outer edge and not the black lines.
So I want to select only the outer shape of the object.
Now I have already tried many things.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Greetings, Elena

Answer (score 1):

Using the magic wand, set the checkbox for 'Contiguous' to on. Click somewhere outside the image, in some 'free space'.
Marked in red, because my computer refuses to show the cursor in screenshots ;)

[image]

Then invert the selection - Select menu or  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>i</kbd>  [Mac] or  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>i</kbd>  [Win]

[image]

What remains is a selection of only the interior of the object

[image]